# Is there a gem which converts form actions into JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I currently have the following form action in my view:

```
"/attacks?attack_type=punch&target_id=6&target_name=Frieza+henchman&target_type=NonPlayerCharacter"
```

I want to render this in my Javascript as JSON so I can send it via websockets. I want it to look like this:

```
var attacks = {
  attack_type: "punch"
  target_id: 6
  target_name: "Frieza henchman"
  target_type: "NonPlayerCharacter"
}
```

Is there a gem which converts form actions into JSON ob

Comment: a queryString parser will work

Comment: are you want to serialize the the form data in javascript?

Comment: if you want to convert in javascript in use the jQuery .serialize() method

Comment: What is the syntax to do that on a form action? I am trying :
$(".attack").attr("action").serialize()
But it is undefined

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 `$('form').serialize();`

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. For some reason it targets my authenticity token and serializes that. To correct this I tried to specify what part of that form I wanted to serialize by specifying the 'action' attribute: " $(".attack").attr("action")"; this gives me the correct string but not as a jquery object so serialize will not work on it.